# Linked Ordered Set or Ordered Linked List?

Tags: java, list, algorithm, data-structures, set

I need an efficient data structure to store a big number (millions) of records on a live (up to a hundred insertions, deletions or updates per second) server.

Its clients need to be able to grab a chunk of that data, sorted, beginning from some point, be able to scroll (i.e. get records before and after the ones they initially got) and receive live updates.

Initially I considered some form of a linked ordered set with some index, however even though the records are unique in the sense that they have an id, the values of their fields by which the set would be ordered are not. Could resolve collisions by just inserting more than one record into each node, but does not seem right.

The other solution I came up with is a linked set with an index, which is kept sorted through insertion deletion and updates. Big O of that would be not O(log n) but O(n), but I'm guessing if I still have the index, would it speed up the process a lot? Or binary search the place to insert? Do not think I can with the list though.

What would be the most efficient solution and which one is best given that I need clients to receive live updates on the state of this data structure?

The code will be in Java

Comment: I think doubly linked list would be appropriate with prev & next pointers pointing to the sets before and prev of the current set, for the sets here, you can use self balancing bst, such as AVL tree insertion/deletion cost would be O(logn)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Java` these kinds of requirements are usually solved by using a `TreeMap` like a database index.  The `TreeMap` interface isn't particularly well designed for this, so there are some tricks to it:

- Your record objects should implement a `Key` interface or base class that just exposes the sort fields and ID.  This interface should *not* extend `Comparable`.
- Your record objects will be both keys *and* values in the TreeMap, and each record will map to itself, but the Key interface will be used as the key, so the type of the map is `TreeMap<Key,Record>`. Remember that every `put` should be of the form `put(record,record)`
- When you make the `TreeMap`, use the constructor that takes a custom comparator.  Pass a comparator that compares `Key`s using the sort fields AND the ID, so that there will be **no duplicates**.
- To search in the map, you can use other implementations of the `Key` interface -- you don't have to use complete records.  Because a caller can't provide an ID, though, you can't use `TreeMap.get()` to find a record that matches the sort fields.  Use a key with ID=0 and `TreeMap.ceilingEntry` to get  the first record with >= key, and then check the sort fields to see if they match.

Note that if you need multiple orderings on different fields, you can make your records implement multiple Key interfaces and put them in multiple maps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Millions of records -> First estimate if you want / can hold all the data in RAM.
2. Have a look at [b-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

   | Algorithm | Average | Worst case |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Space | O(n) | O(n) |
   | Search | O(log n) | O(log n) |
   | Insert | O(log n) | O(log n) |
   | Delete | O(log n) | O(log n) |